# How to emulate Pan using SOX

Tags: audio, panning

Pan effect is deprecated in SOX, actually we have to use the remix effect.

As i know, pan is not just an attenuation of one channel but follow the [Pan Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_law),
how can i use sox to implement pan correctly?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried searching with google?
my 2nd hit on "sox audio panning"

http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/348768-sox-audio-mixing-4-channels-down-to-2

Comment: yes i read it, but it is not an equal-power algorithm implementation, is it?

Comment: Perhaps in the future you can let us know what you've already tried. And, as far as i understand, it is not possible, it says so in the post right? Perhaps you can contact the developer or their forum?

Comment: i believe it is possible, implementing the algorithm and a pan law. I will post it if i succeed